# Line Appearing in Mesh after resizing

Tags: modeling, artifacts

I'm a Blender beginner and I'm wondering why a line appears in my mesh after resizing the shown ring of vertices. I shrunk it a little. Before there was no line. My goal is to add more curvature to the top of this bottle.

How I resized the top ring:
[image]

Line appears after resizing:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! The answer of moonboots should probably fix it. In case u have difficulties pls share your blend file https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've probably accidentally ripped your edge, now you have 2 separate meshes, to merge the overlapping vertices select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> to *Merge by Distance* and it should fix the problem